# dispalying subwindow in PYQt python

Tags: python, pyqt

i am new to PyQt and working on building a small desktop application using PyQt. i am trying to add a button on main window and when i press that button, i want to display a sub window with some text on it. after searching a lot i tried something from my side and end up with following code. but its not working. can someone guide me on the same.

```
def window():
 app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 w = QtGui.QWidget()
 def show_html():
    w2 = QtGui.QWidget(w)
    html_source = QPlainTextEdit(w2)
    html_source.setPlainText("Some text here")
    html_source.move(700,50)
    w2.setGeometry(1000,1000,750,400)
    w2.setWindowTitle("Source Code")
    w2.show()

 generate_html = QtGui.QPushButton("Show HTML", w)
 generate_html.clicked.connect(show_html)

 w.setGeometry(2000,2000,1500,800)
 w.setWindowTitle("Fanwen Crawler")
 w.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
window()
```

when i am clicking on Show HTML button, its not showing the other window.

Answer (score -1):

the only reason this code was not working is - i didn't defined my child window in the main window, so it was not executing.the code should be-

```
def window():
 app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 w = QtGui.QWidget()
 w2 = QtGui.QWidget(w)
 def show_html():

    html_source = QPlainTextEdit(w2)
    html_source.setPlainText("Some text here")
    html_source.move(700,50)
    w2.setGeometry(1000,1000,750,400)
    w2.setWindowTitle("Source Code")
    w2.show()

 generate_html = QtGui.QPushButton("Show HTML", w)
 generate_html.clicked.connect(show_html)
 w.setGeometry(2000,2000,1500,800)
 w.setWindowTitle("Fanwen Crawler")
 w.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__': 
 window()
```

Comment: ashish the code posed by avstennit is much cleaner, readable, and follows the standards typically employed in pyqt programs. Yours might work, but I would look to asvstennit's code as a model of how to write pyqt programs.

Comment: yes i agree that, but that answer was not the solution of my problem. The solution is in the above answer which i have posted, actually the problem was because of declaring the child window in the main window.